# How to prove that images were stolen?

Tags: watermark

How can I prove that images were stolen from a website? 
Is there any way to check **from when** an another website have the same images? I have no any access to the server.
Thanks for **any** idea!

UPDATE:
No, I'm not the one who forgot watermark. An old client of mine just found me with this question. Actually found Google cached page which we can use, but still interested if any other solution is exist. Like any image format contains any date attribute in it?

Comment: Seriously though, I doubt it, especially with no access to server logs which are unlikely to tell you anyway. In the future it'd be best to either implement JavaScript to stop the user right clicking and saving (though that is still susceptible to screenshots). If they are important images, consider watermarking them.

Comment: thanks for great info. on Google its visible BUT this is not the question, I'm interested in if it's somehow burned into an image.

Comment: @LeopoldScotch JavaScript will not prevent experienced users from saving the images. You could save it after turning JavaScript off unless the picture itself is coded as background, read the source HTML unless the URL is dynamically generated (and even then inspect the element in Chrome or Firebug), sniff the packets to find outgoing requests or even collect it from the cache directory. As you're pointing out, images you care about should be protected by other means. However, as long as you're publishing the image to be downloaded and displayed, it'll always be possible to save as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Unix-based operating system, you might have access to cURL. Try running

```
curl --remote-time --remote-name http://url-to-your-image/
```

and see if you get a timestamp that is different from the exact time you downloaded the file. Not all servers respond with the time, but it might be worth an attempt.

But generally, if it's your original work, then you should have a copy of the image with higher resolution and/or lower compression rate, right? That should be enough to prove which of the images is the stolen one. Intellectual property rights on the Internet is a mess, though, for several reasons. But even if you can't take legal actions, you might have better luck convincing an administrator to remove the content.

Comment: Awesome great info, thanks! totally forgot cURL and it was extremely handy! thanks a lot @Anders!